# Click on an image stored in a MySQL database table and get additional row content for that image

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a members.php page that connects to a database table.  The table has the following fields: id, username, profile image.

The following PHP code displays the profile image for each user in rows of 6 and allows each image to be clickable.

```
<?php
            // The code below will display the current users who have created accounts with:  **datemeafterdark.com**
            $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profile_aboutyou");
            $row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            
            $id = $row1["id"];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
            
            $profileimagepath = $row1["profileimagepath"];
            $_SESSION['profileimagepath'] = $profileimagepath;
            
            
              $count = 0;
                  while($dispImg=mysql_fetch_array($result))
                      {
                          if($count==6) //6 images per row
                              {
                                  print "</tr>";
                                  $count = 0;
                              }
                          if($count==0)
                              print "<tr>";
                                  print "<td>";
        ?>                          
                                    <center>
                                        <a href="viewmemberprofile.php"><img src="<?php echo $dispImg['profileimagepath'];?>" width="85px;" height="85px;"></a>
                                    </center>
                           <?php
                                        $count++;
                                  print "</td>";
                      }           
                                  if($count>0)
                              print "</tr>";
                              
                           ?>
```

This is all great, however, when I click on the image that loads it re-directs me to: viewmemberprofile.php which is what it is supposed to do.  But it always displays the same image with the same id value (i.e.) 150 no matter which image I click.  What I would like to have happened is.  If I click on an image with id 155 etc...  it will display content for that image data field not consistently the same image data regardless of which image I click.

*Your help and guidance would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.*

One thing that I forgot to mention is that I do use sessions so... when I am re-directed to the viewmemberprofile.php page I use the following code to aide in getting the data that I need from the table.

```
          <?php
            $id = $_SESSION['id'];
            echo($id);
          ?>
          <?php
            echo('<br>');
          ?>
          <?php
            $profileimagepath = $_SESSION['profileimagepath'];
          ?>
          <img src="<?php echo($profileimagepath);?>" width="50px;" height="50px;">
```

I have yet to impliment the suggested solution.

Comment: (1) Make sure you have put session_start() at the start of the PHP scripts (2) mysql_query is deprecated, please use either mysqli or PDO

Comment: 1. This should not be done using the session in the first place. 2. _"The following PHP code displays the profile image for each user"_ - no it doesn't; you are fetching the first record _before_ the while loop already, but never output the data of that record - so the first user gets skipped.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the ID of the row to `viewmemberprofile.php`, e.g.:

```
<a href="viewmemberprofile.php?id=<?= $dispImg['profileimagepath'] ?>">
```

And `viewmemberprofile.php` needs to select that row from the DB:

```
SELECT * FROM profile_aboutyou WHERE id = $_GET['id']
```

The above SQL statement is pseudo-code; you need to write actual code to accomplish what it is describing, preferably using [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712037/what-is-parameterized-query).

Comment: Above answer was not really detailed enough.  Still very much lost.

Comment: @user3509661 Please describe what was not clear and what you need further details about.